# C++ - Object Oriented File System Design using Composite Design Pattern

Tags: c++, object-oriented, design-patterns, file-system

I am trying to come up with a good File System Design using C++ / OOP. This is being done to gain an understanding of System Design and Design Patterns.

I have some basic functionality, like reading and writing files, adding and deleting files and folders, calculating the size of files and folders. The design pattern I am trying to use is [Composite Design pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/composite-design-pattern/).

My design uses a base class called `BaseComponent` which contains facilities common to both files and folders.  The class `Folder` deals with adding and deleting of files and folders while class `File` deals with reading and writing of files.  Both `File` and `Folder` are derived from `BaseComponent`.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

class BaseComponent
{
    std::string name_v;
    BaseComponent* parent_v;
    bool is_folder;
public:
    BaseComponent(std::string name, BaseComponent* parent = nullptr, bool f = true) : name_v{name}, parent_v{parent}, is_folder{f}
    {
    }

    virtual ~BaseComponent()
    {

    }

    void change_name(std::string& name)
    {
        name_v = name;
    }

    std::string name() const
    {
        return name_v;
    }

    BaseComponent* parent() const
    {
        return parent_v;
    }

    void del()
    {
        if(parent_v == nullptr)
        {
            return;
        }
        parent_v -> delete_component(this);
    }
    virtual int size() const
    {
        return 0;
    }
    virtual void add_component(BaseComponent*)
    {

    }
    virtual void delete_component(BaseComponent*)
    {

    }
};

class Folder : public BaseComponent
{
    std::set<BaseComponent*> children;
public:
    Folder(std::string name, Folder* parent = nullptr, bool is_folder = true) : BaseComponent{name, parent, is_folder}
    {

    }

    ~Folder()
    {

    }

    int size() const
    {
        int size_v = 0;
        for(auto child : children)
        {
            size_v += child -> size();
        }
        return size_v;
    }

    int num_ff()
    {
        return children.size();
    }

    void add_component(BaseComponent* b)
    {
        children.insert(b);
    }

    void delete_component(BaseComponent* b)
    {
        children.erase(b);
    }
};

class File : public BaseComponent
{
    std::string contents_v;
public:
    File(std::string contents, std::string name, Folder* parent, bool is_folder = false) : BaseComponent{name, parent, is_folder}, contents_v{contents}
    {
    }

    ~File()
    {

    }
    int size() const
    {
        return sizeof(this);
    }

    void write(std::string content)
    {
        contents_v = content;
    }

    std::string read() const
    {
        return contents_v;
    }

};

/*class FileSystem
{

};*/

int main()
{
    Folder root{"/"};
    Folder home{"home", &root};
    root.add_component(&home);
    Folder lib{"lib", &root};
    root.add_component(&lib);
    Folder dev{"dev", &root};
    root.add_component(&dev);
    std::cout << "No. of components in root: " << root.num_ff() << "\n";
    std::cout << "No. of components in home: " << home.num_ff() << "\n";
    File test{"x = 0, y = 0", "Configuration.txt", &root};
    root.add_component(&test);
    Folder ws{"ws", &home};
    home.add_component(&ws);
    File fs{"fs file", "fs.cpp", &ws};
    ws.add_component(&fs);
    File git{"user: dummy", "git_config", &home};
    home.add_component(&git);
    std::cout << "Contents of git: " << git.read() << "\n";
    git.write("user: new\n email:new@new.com");
    std::cout << "Contents of git: " << git.read() << "\n";
    std::cout << "No. of components in root: " << root.num_ff() << "\n";
    std::cout << "No. of components in home: " << home.num_ff() << "\n";
    std::cout << "No. of components in ws: " << ws.num_ff() << "\n";
    dev.del();
    std::cout << "No. of components in root: " << root.num_ff() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Size of git: " << git.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Size of root: " << root.size() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

1. The `add_component` is being called from `main`. How can I change that? I don't mind calling it inside a new class called `FileSystem` by creating functions such as `mkdir` or `mkfile` to handle folder and file creation. But I am not able to come up with a good design.
2. If `FileSystem` is being implemented, I would like to avoid having to take the pointer to parent inside the `main`, while creating files and folders. This is again something that is stopping me from coming up with a better design.
3. How to improve the functionalities implemented? Are there any significant issues in this part?
4. Is a better design possible without changing classes and their interface?
5. Kindly provide an overall review.

Comment: Have you looked at how (proposed) `std::filesystem` represents these, or is this a completely independent approach?

Comment: @TobySpeight I haven't looked into std::filesystem as I didn't know that it existed. However, my objective is to learn system design. So I need to implement it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that jumps out immediately is the `is_folder` member.  It's a bad sign if a base class needs to know what subclass it is.  Even more concerning, the subclass constructors allow one to create a `File` with `is_folder` set, or a `Folder` with `is_folder` reset.  Thankfully, this member seems never to be used, so it can be omitted altogether.

---

I think that `BaseComponent` ought to be an abstract class.  A simple way to do so is to make `size()` a *pure* virtual method:

```
virtual std::size_t size() const = 0;
```

(I've used a more appropriate return type, too - though some platforms support files larger than addressable memory, so be careful).

---

Similarly, the destructor that's declared just to make it virtual (well done for remembering) can be defined `=default`:

```
virtual ~BaseComponent() = default;
```

The subclass destructors can be omitted, as the compiler-generated ones will be exactly equivalent.

---

We can save the two-step construct-then-add by having the constructor also add to the parent entry:

```
BaseComponent::BaseComponent(std::string name, Folder* parent)
    : name_v{std::move(name)},
      parent_v{parent}
{
    if (parent) {
        parent->add_component(this);
    }
}
```

It also makes sense for a destructor to remove the object from its parent (otherwise we could end up with dangling references), and for a deleted `Folder` to null out its children's parent pointers.

---

We can help avoid mistakes by using the `override` keyword when we reimplement `size()` in the subclasses:

```
std::size_t size() const override
{
    return sizeof this;
}
```

BTW, I hope that `sizeof this` is just a placeholder for something more useful later (all pointers to `File` objects will have the same size on any given system).  You probably meant `return contents_v.size();` there.

---

Minor points:

- `num_ff()` should be `const`
- Constructor arguments passed by value should be `std::move()`d to their new homes.
- `BaseComponent` constructor and destructor can be `protected`.  Consider suppressing copy construction and copy assignment.
- `BaseComponent` isn't a very informative name.

---

## Modified code

```
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <set>

class Folder;
class File;

class FileSystemObject
{
    std::string name_v;
    Folder* parent_v;

protected:
    FileSystemObject(std::string name, Folder* parent);

    FileSystemObject(const FileSystemObject&) = delete;
    FileSystemObject& operator=(const FileSystemObject&) = delete;

    virtual ~FileSystemObject();

public:
    void change_name(std::string& name)
    {
        name_v = name;
    }

    std::string name() const
    {
        return name_v;
    }

    Folder* parent() const
    {
        return parent_v;
    }

    virtual std::size_t size() const = 0;

    void set_parent(Folder* parent);
};


class Folder : public FileSystemObject
{
    std::set<FileSystemObject*> children = {};
public:
    Folder(std::string name, Folder* parent = nullptr)
        : FileSystemObject{std::move(name), parent}
    {
    }

    ~Folder()
    {
        for (auto c: children) {
            c->set_parent(nullptr);
        }
    }

    std::size_t size() const override
    {
        return std::accumulate(children.begin(), children.end(), 0,
                               [](auto sum, auto child){ return sum + child->size(); });
    }

    int num_ff() const
    {
        return children.size();
    }

    void add_component(FileSystemObject* b)
    {
        children.insert(b);
    }

    void delete_component(FileSystemObject* b)
    {
        children.erase(b);
    }
};


class File : public FileSystemObject
{
    std::string contents_v;
public:
    File(std::string contents, std::string name, Folder* parent)
        : FileSystemObject{name, parent},
          contents_v{contents}
    {
    }

    std::size_t size() const override
    {
        return contents_v.size();
    }

    void write(std::string content)
    {
        contents_v = std::move(content);
    }

    std::string read() const
    {
        return contents_v;
    }

};

FileSystemObject::FileSystemObject(std::string name, Folder* parent)
    : name_v{std::move(name)},
      parent_v{parent}
{
    if (parent) {
        parent->add_component(this);
    }
}


FileSystemObject::~FileSystemObject()
{
    if (parent_v) {
        parent_v->delete_component(this);
    }
}

void FileSystemObject::set_parent(Folder* parent)
{
    if (parent_v) {
        parent_v->delete_component(this);
    }
    if ((parent_v = parent)) {    // assignment!
        parent_v->add_component(this);
    }
}


#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Folder root{"/"};
    Folder home{"home", &root};
    Folder lib{"lib", &root};
    Folder dev{"dev", &root};
    std::cout << "No. of components in root: " << root.num_ff() << '\n';
    std::cout << "No. of components in home: " << home.num_ff() << '\n';
    File test{"x = 0, y = 0", "Configuration.txt", &root};
    Folder ws{"ws", &home};
    File fs{"fs file", "fs.cpp", &ws};
    File git{"user: dummy", "git_config", &home};
    std::cout << "Contents of git: " << git.read() << '\n';
    git.write("user: new\n email:new@new.com");
    std::cout << "Contents of git: " << git.read() << '\n';
    std::cout << "No. of components in root: " << root.num_ff() << '\n';
    std::cout << "No. of components in home: " << home.num_ff() << '\n';
    std::cout << "No. of components in ws: " << ws.num_ff() << '\n';
    dev.set_parent(nullptr);
    std::cout << "No. of components in root: " << root.num_ff() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Size of git: " << git.size() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Size of root: " << root.size() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the review (upvoted). I tried using `add_component` inside the constructor similar to what you have shown, but I missed the check for `nullptr`. I thought the problem was because the base class was calling derived class member inside constructor even though `parent` was already constructed.

Comment: It's also important to note the forward declaration of `class Folder` so we can use `Folder*` for members and parameters, and moving the definition of the constructor and destructor to after `Folder`, so we can use its methods.